# How to check older WordPress versions?

Tags: wordpress

I want to know how to check if a WordPress installation is lower than some version. So let's say i want to check if a WordPress installation is below `3.4`.

How do i do that ?

**What is important here is that a version can also be something like `4.1.1` which isn't a float either.**

How do i check if the version is lower than the current version `4.1.1`?

Comment: you mean with code or where to find the version in the backend?

Comment: Excuse me, I mean with php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo bloginfo('version'); ?>
```

bloginfo('version') returns the wordpress version.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

So based on your comments what you could do in this specific case would be

```
$wp_version = bloginfo('version');
$wp_version = substr('$wp_version', 0, 2);  <-- gets the x.x digits to compare
$wp_version_num = floatval($wp_version);
if($wp_version_num <= 3.4) {
   echo "less than equal";
}
else{
   echo "greater";
}
```

What I did here was take the string cut it up to one decimal then convert it to a float like you wanted.

Comment: I already know that using bloginfo('version') returns the current version of WordPress. But the return type is a string. Not an integer or a float. I want to know how to safely compare the current version with some other older version.

Comment: What is important here is that a version can also be somthing like `4.1.1` which isn't a float either.

Comment: So you need it to be a string? What are you asking?

Comment: Well version can be `3.4`, `3.6` and so on. That would perfectly translate to a float value which can be checked. But how do you compare `4.1.1` (current version of WordPress) with `3.4` ?

Comment: Is that your goal to check vs 3.4 ?

Comment: Yes i am currently creating a plugin but there are functions i need to use that may cause an error if WordPress version below `3.4` is used. I am using version `4.1.1`